# Android SoundPoolクラスのmp3再生について

Tags: android

SoundPoolクラスでループなしに設定してmp3を再生すると、特定の端末(Motorola Xoom:Android 4.0.3で確認)で２回再生されているように聞こえるのですが、
解決策はないでしょうか。

```
SoundPool pool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
int soundId = pool.load(path, 1);
pool.play(soundId, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1, 0, 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

音声ファイルをoggフォーマットに変更することで解決しますよ
mp3では正しく再生されないことがあるようです。
参考としてこちらのリンクを貼りました。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547551/issue-with-soundpool-and-samsung-galaxy-s